# Asterisk Siptrunk Registration with multiple numbers assigned

Tags: asterisk

I made a registration on my Asterisk in the sip.conf as following:

```
register => myusername:mypassword:myusername@sip.test.com/720202020
```

So incoming calls works for 720202020. My question is can I add more numbers(DIDs) to the same register line, or do I need to duplicate the line with the second number(DID)?

Like this;

```
register => myusername:mypassword:myusername@sip.test.com/720202020
register => myusername:mypassword:myusername@sip.test.com/720202021
```

Maybe this is possible:

```
register => myusername:mypassword:myusername@sip.test.com/720202020/720202021
```